# Generating normally distributed samples

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

need help understanding these lines of code! what I have here is 3 sub population: 10, 30, and 50 each normally distributed with their respective std dev and mean as shown: for e.g.: sub population 10 would have a std dev of 3000 and mean 10,000. what I want to do is to conduct random sampling of these sub population and put the results in a list I named "sample". question is: did I code my objective correctly in the line of sample += np.random.normal(mean_List[I], std_list[I], sub_pop[I]).tolist()?

```
sub_pop = [10, 30, 50]
std_list = [3000, 5000, 8000]
mean_list = [10000, 15000, 30000]
sample = []
for i in range(len(sub_pop)):
sample += np.random.normal(mean_list[i],std_list[i], sub_pop[i]).tolist()
sample1 = [abs(x) for x in sample]
print(sample1)
print(np.median(sample1))
```

Comment: Does it give you an output that you expect?

Comment: im not too sure, it seems right. but I want to understand the logic behind the code

Comment: like what does "sample += np.random.normal(mean_list[I], std_list[I], sub_pop[I]).tolist() do exactly? I know it randomly picks data from the data I have. but wad Im unsure is, when I do this, does python know I want sub_pop 10 to be mapped with std_list 3000 and mean_list 10,000 and sub_pop 30 mapped with std_list of 5000 and mean_list of 15000 and so on

Comment: What part is unclear though? You described what you want to do and then showed the code that you've implemented to do it

Comment: by writing mean_list[I], std_list[I], sub_pop[I] in the np.random.normal function, does it do exactly that?

Comment: `sample` is an empty list. `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]` would give `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` through _list concatenation_. Numpy generates an array of samples for you, you then call the `tolist()` method to convert it back to a python list, and then concatenate it with `sample`

Comment: I understand that part, but would python know that when drawing the randomly generated sample, the sub_pop of 10 Is grouped together wif the std dev of 3000 and mean 10,000 and so on. I'm pretty new to python so pardon me if I don't know the technical terms for these.

Comment: Yes, because you are making a single call to numpy, giving it the parameters and specifying the number of results it should return from the single call. So, for each iteration of the loop, you're calling for a full sample size with a single set of constraints/parameters.

Comment: ok got it! so the code I've written achieves what I want to do?

Comment: I think I've found an issue. Give me 5 mins to sort an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it seems that you know what the code is doing already and just want some assurance that you're calling the `numpy` method with the correct parameters. I think there is one issue in your current code: you're merging all of your populations into a single output sample.

To illustrate this, I've bumped the population sizes up to 5000 for plotting. If you don't clear the `sample` list on each iteration, you just keep adding to it:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sub_pop = [5000, 5000, 5000]
std_list = [3000, 5000, 8000]
mean_list = [10000, 15000, 30000]
sample = []
for i in range(len(sub_pop)):
    sample += np.random.normal(mean_list[i],std_list[i], sub_pop[i]).tolist()
    sample1 = [abs(x) for x in sample]

plt.hist(sample, bins=500)
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('all_merged.png')
```

Which gives:
[image]

Instead, I think you probably want three separate populations. If you *don't* want separate populations, at least it serves as clarification over whether you're getting the output you expect :)

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sub_pop = [5000, 5000, 5000]
std_list = [3000, 5000, 8000]
mean_list = [10000, 15000, 30000]
sample = []
for i in range(len(sub_pop)):
    sample += np.random.normal(mean_list[i],std_list[i], sub_pop[i]).tolist()
    sample1 = [abs(x) for x in sample]

    plt.hist(sample, bins=500)
    sample = [] # Clear the sample list
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('separated.png')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for clearing my doubt! for this case, I do not want it separate as what I'm trying to do is draw samples from 3 different distributions, put it together in a list and then find the median